# Failed to build preview for function. Reason: PhantomServerIncorrectRespons (C1ConsoleAccess.xml)

Tags: c1-cms

We have a internet facing instance of Composite-C1 we are using for QA'ing our site, and when we try to force [HTTPS for console access](http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/C1-Console-Access) (forceHttps), the FunctionPreview is broken in the Page editor. There is a valid SSL cert on the server. Our side does support HTTPS, but it's not required for the public content.

```
<ClientProtocol forceHttps="true" allowFallbackToHttp="false" customHttpsPortNumber="" />
```

We are seeing these errors in the C1 Logs

> *Failed to build preview for function. Reason: PhantomServerIncorrectResponse; Output:
>   ERROR, page.open: fail*
>
> *Shutting down PhantomJs server. Reason: PhantomServerIncorrectResponse, Output: ERROR, page.open: fail*

Setting forceHttps="false" in the ~/App_Data/Composite/Configuration/C1ConsoleAccess.xml file along with a Server Restart will bring back the FunctionPreview.

Any debugging tips?

Answer (score 1):

With the release of [Composite C1 5.1](https://compositec1.codeplex.com/releases/view/625732), We surgically pulled out an updated version of PhantomJS.exe and copied it over to our C1 5.0 deployment. This appears to fix the problems we were experiencing.

PhantonJS.exe

Old Version: 1.9.7.0

New Version: 2.1.1.1

Folder: /App_Data/Composite/PhantomJs